# How to return random picture via jquery

Tags: jquery, css, random

I want to get random picture from [api.getlove.cn](http://api.getlove.cn/api/img). So I have a `button` to click to get one.But it  only return the same image  when I click the button.Here is my partly code:

`$(".btn").css("background-image",'url(' +"http://api.getlove.cn/api/img" + ')');`

I don't know why it do not return random picture,what is wrong with my code?How can I get random pic when I click the button?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well that is because browser caches the image loaded for first time. and as same url is being called, it takes the cached image instead of loading fresh one. You should add a random parameter to url(by adding random number of timestamp) to make new url which will be loaded again:

```
 $(".btn").css("background-image",'url(' +"http://api.getlove.cn/api/img?t=" +Math.floor(Date.now() / 1000)+ ')');
```

```js
$(".btn").click(function(){
  $('body').css("background-image",'url(' +"http://api.getlove.cn/api/img?t=" +Math.floor(Date.now() / 1000)+ ')');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class="btn">click here</button>
```

Comment: It solved ! Thanks,and you let me got some new knowledge about brower.

Comment: @LilySun: glad it helps :)